# How to print the log in android chromium?

Tags: android, chromium

I am new at worknig on android chromium, and I need to print the log msg in it, then how to print the log in android chromium, which interface can be used to print log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There several ways to print the log in android chromium, and you try the two flowing ways:

```
1. The first way:    
//Add the head file   
#include <cutils/log.h>
#define XLOGC(...) android_printLog(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Your Tags", __VA_ARGS__)

//use the XLOGC to print the log
XLOGC("Your log message"); 


2. The second way:
//Add the head file   
#include "base/logging.h"
LOG(INFO) << "Your log message";
```